# Why does the UITextView can obstruct the main thread in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

Every time the app pushes a controller containing a text view, the screen will stop a second.Just like the effect that you put an internet request in the main thread. I have tried to initialize the text view in the global queue,but it didn't work.

the text view belongs to the customized view named "FNMFeedbackTitleView".
the code of the text view initializing as the following:

```
@implementation FNMFeedbackTitleView
NSInteger currentWords = 0;

NSString *_currentText = nil;
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = FNWhiteColor;
        currentWords = 0;
        _currentText = nil;
        [self initializedSubviews];//containing the initializing of text view    }
    return self;
}
```

the initializing as the following:

```
//text view initialize
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
textView.frame= CGRectMake(horizonalMargin, CGRectGetMaxY(adviceLabel.frame)+verticalMargin, FNDeviceWidth-2*horizonalMargin, 100);
textView.delegate = self;
textView.backgroundColor = FNWhiteColor;
[self addSubview:textView];
_textView = textView;
```

the customized view (FNMFeedbackTitleView)'s initializing of FNMFeedbackViewController as the following:

```
 //titleView
    _titleView = [[FNMFeedbackTitleView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, FNDeviceWidth, 100)];
```

the customized view will be a header view in collectionview

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableView = nil;
    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
        reusableView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"headerview" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (reusableView.subviews.count ==  0) {
            [reusableView addSubview:_titleView];
        }
    }else {
        reusableView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"footerview" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (reusableView.subviews.count ==  0) {
            [reusableView addSubview:_footerView];
        }
    }
    return reusableView;
}
```

the push action :

```
FNMFeedbackViewController *feedbackController = [FNMFeedbackViewController new];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:feedbackController animated:YES];
```

Comment: show some code relating to this so we can see what you are doing

Comment: How much text do you have in the text view? Could it be considered hard to render? What does instruments.app tell?

Comment: nothing in the text view .just  set the placeholder. I haven't use the instruments to check

Comment: so if you remove the adding of the textView it doesn't stop for a moment?

Comment: yep,you are right.so I did think it causes by the text view.